# python ファイルの読み込み

Tags: python

以下のコードは指定のテキストファイル (ave.txt) を読み込み、平均気温を出すプログラムです。

**現状のコード:**

```
path = "ave.txt"
sum=0.0
a=0
with open(path,"r") as f:
    for l in f:
        l=l.strip()
        b= l.split(',')
        if len(b)==1:
            name=(b[0].strip('"'))
        if len(b) == 2:
            sum += float(b[1].strip('"'))
            a+=1

print(f"{name}の平均気温は{sum/a}度です")
```

**ave.txt**

```
"東京"
"1月","-3.6"
"2月","-3.1"
"3月","0.6"
"4月","7.1"
"5月","12.4"
"6月","16.7"
"7月","20.5"
"8月","22.3"
"9月","18.1"
"10月","11.8"
"11月","4.9"
"12月","-0.9"
```

ファイルを読み込んで、平均気温を出すプログラムです。
そこで、この式の `b` を表示するとこうなっています。

**b の表示結果:**

```
['"東京"']
['"1月"', '"-3.6"']
['"2月"', '"-3.1"']
['"3月"', '"0.6"']
['"4月"', '"7.1"']
['"5月"', '"12.4"']
['"6月"', '"16.7"']
['"7月"', '"20.5"']
['"8月"', '"22.3"']
['"9月"', '"18.1"']
['"10月"', '"11.8"']
['"11月"', '"4.9"']
['"12月"', '"-0.9"']
```

この状態から以下の状態にしたいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか？

**期待する表示結果:**

```
1月：-3.6度↩
2月：-3.1度↩
3月：0.6度↩
4月：7.1度↩
5月：12.4度↩
6月：16.7度↩
7月：20.5度↩
8月：22.3度↩
9月：18.1度↩
10月：11.8度↩
11月：4.9度↩
12月：-0.9度↩
```

'""'を消して、,の代わりに:を入れたいです。
表示するのは、月と気温だけで、一行目の東京は表示しません。

Comment: 「と書かれたave.txtファイルがあります。」では先頭のデータは「"東京"」ですが、「この式のbを表示するとこうなっています。」では先頭のデータは「['"札幌市"']」となっています。なぜデータが変わってしまうのでしょうか？

Comment: 読み込み自体は出来ているように見えるので、もう少し問題点を詳しく言葉で説明した方が回答も付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

拡張子は`.txt`ですが、データ内容的には`CSV`の形式に沿っているようですね。

せっかくなので基本的な書き方だけの多数の行で実現するよりも、標準で用意されている[csv](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html)モジュールを使うことも考えた方が良いでしょう。

こんな風に出来ます。

```
import csv
path = 'ave.txt'
#### sum = 0.0
#### a = 0
with open(path, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    name = next(spamreader)[0]
    for row in spamreader:
        #### sum += float(row[1])
        #### a += 1
        print(f'{row[0]}：{row[1]}度')

#### print(f"{name}の平均気温は{sum/a}度です")
```

元のソースの「期待する表示結果」に必要ない部分は`####`でコメントアウトしています。
また表示結果の方は全角のコロン`：`のようなので、print()ではそちらを指定しています。

`encoding=`はファイルの内容に従って変更してください。
`delimiter=`や`quotechar=`はデフォルトの値と同じなので指定しなくても良いのですが、参照ページの`短い利用例:`では変更して使用していたので元に戻して明記しています。